# Downloading Selenium 2.0 without using Maven

Tags: java, selenium, download

I have been attempting to download Selenium 2.0, which the site for essentially forces you to use Maven in order to do so.  I have no experience using Maven and thus want to download Selenium 2.0 without it, is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean? The download page has everything downloadable, a server jar, a client zip file with libraries in it.

Comment: What problems did you have downloading from http://seleniumhq.org/download/?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from their site:

> http://seleniumhq.org/download/

I found that by googling "selenium download" btw.